# HOW CHANGE PSEUDO CODE TO EMU8086 CODE?CAN HELP ME?

Tags: emu8086

Integer A,B
C=A2xB
IF(C=0)THEN C=C+1 ELSE C=AXORB

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is simply to code.

---

pseudo code is made to be read by humans not computers, try think of it as instructions on what your program should do (or what you want it to do)

E.G

```
If 1 is equal to 2 then return 'three'
```

=>

```js
if (1 == 2) {
 return 'three' 
}
```